# Unity3d Admob Reward Based Video error

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, chartboost

having problem showing rewarded ads using ad-mob SDK for Unity3d.
i successfully showing banner and interstitial ads, but when trying to show
rewarded ads i get the fallowing error (logcat):

> Starting ad request.
>   06-20 13:35:17.278 1188-1211/com.dice.master W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>   06-20 13:35:17.279 1188-1188/com.dice.master W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
>   06-20 13:35:17.319 1188-1188/com.dice.master I/Unity: HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad event received with message: Internal error
>                                                         UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
>                                                         UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
>                                                         UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
>                                                         UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>                                                         UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineMonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:106)
>                                                         AdController:HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(Object, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at D:\Private\Dice master 3D\Assets\Scripts\Admob\AdController.cs:133)
>                                                         GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:m__1E(Object, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs) (at D:\Private\Dice master 3D\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:60)
>                                                         GoogleMobileAds.Android.RewardBasedVideoAdClient:onAdFailedToLoad(String) (at D:\Private\Dice master 3D\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Android\RewardBasedVideoAdClient.cs:84)
>                                                         System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[]

i have an account in Chartboost ,set app with basic settings.
added the Mediation in the admob account to the add unit.....
the implementing is pretty straightforward so....

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0 means there is no fill. I've never worked with charboost but there should be one of these: if charboost has test ads - enable them, if you just finished setting up charboost dashboard it may take some time to start working. But if these don't work than probably you are from 3rd world country like me and have very low fill. In this case download a free VPN app, start it and test again.

Comment: Hi Nika,so any recommended Reward Based Video network for 3rd country (for Unity)?

Comment: not really, I don't know any. Thing is, Developed countries have more financial potential, so better chances of buying new game/app. Thus ADVERTISERS chose to direct 9 ads out of 10 to developed countries. Ad PROVIDERS (like charboost) just implement this behavior. And this is the way absolute majority of ad networks work, not only rewarded video providers. I test my ads with BetterNet VPN, it's free, but there are a lot of other free VPNs out there.

Answer (score 0):

Internal error !try late again.

if continue not able to load ,you can download https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob and run it on device to test if your device and admob id is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try switch between Wi-fi network and 4G. Also you can try to use the google app id and reward id to test in a real device.